# how to parse this text in c#

Tags: c#, parsing

```
abc  = tamaz feeo maa roo key gaera porla
Xyz = gippaza eka jaguar ammaz te sanna.
```

i want to make a struct

```
public struct word
{
 public string Word;
 public string Definition;
}
```

how i can parse them and make a list of `<word>` in c#.

how i can parse it in c#

**thanks for help but it is a text and it is not sure that a line or more so what i do for newline**

Comment: Any reason for choosing to use a `struct` rather than a class? And more so, making it mutable, with public fields? An immutable struct could make sense, although it would be just as reasonable to use a class.

Comment: For an answer to your latest edition to the question, take a look at my answer. It uses the method File.ReadAllLines to handle your newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Split at an = sign. Take at most two parts (word and definition); 
//    ignore any = signs in the definition
string[] parts = line.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2);

word w = new word();
w.Word = parts[0].Trim();

// If the definition is missing then parts.Length == 1
if (parts.Length == 1)
    w.Definition = string.Empty;
else
    w.Definition = parts[1].Trim();

words.Add(w);
```

Comment: No need for array. `String.Split` also accepts single `char` as param

Comment: Only the `params char[]` overload accepts a single `char`. The other overloads (such as the `char[], int` I'm using above) need an explicit array.

Answer (score 4):

Read the input line by line and split by the equal sign.

```
class Entry
{
    private string term;
    private string definition;

    Entry(string term, string definition)
    {
        this.term = term;
        this.definition = definition;
    }
}

// ...

string[] data = line.Split('=');
string word = data[0].Trim();
string definition = data[1].Trim();

Entry entry = new Entry(word, definition);
```

Comment: Just add .Trim() to get rid any extra whitespace

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done using a very simple LINQ query:

```
var definitions =
    from line in File.ReadAllLines(file)
    let parts = line.Split('=')
    select new word
        {
            Word = parts[0].Trim(),
            Definition = parts[1].Trim()
        }
```

Comment: A really concise solution, up (and do you think the regexp i propose it is well?)

Answer (score 1):

Using RegExp you can proceed in two ways, depending on your source input

---

**Exemple 1**

Assuming you have read your source and saved any single line in a vector or list :

```
string[] input = { "abc  = tamaz feeo maa roo key gaera porla", "Xyz = gippaza eka jaguar ammaz te sanna." };

 Regex mySplit = new Regex("(\\w+)\\s*=\\s*((\\w+).*)");

 List<word> mylist = new List<word>();

 foreach (string wordDef in input)
 {
      Match myMatch = mySplit.Match(wordDef);

      word myWord;

      myWord.Word = myMatch.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
      myWord.Definition = myMatch.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value;

       mylist.Add(myWord);
 }
```

**Exemple 2**

Assuming you have read your source in a single variable (and any line is terminated with the line break character '\n') you can use the same regexp "(\w+)\s*=\s*((\w+).*)" but in this way

```
string inputs = "abc  = tamaz feeo maa roo, key gaera porla\r\nXyz = gippaza eka jaguar; ammaz: te sanna.";

MatchCollection myMatches = mySplit.Matches(inputs);

foreach (Match singleMatch in myMatches)
{

    word myWord;

    myWord.Word = singleMatch.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
    myWord.Definition = singleMatch.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value;

    mylist.Add(myWord);
}
```

---

**Lines that matches or does not match the regexp "*(\w+)\s*=\s*((\w+).*)*":**

- "abc =            tamaz feeo maa roo key gaera porla,qsdsdsqdqsd\n" --> **Match!**
- "Xyz= gippaza eka jaguar ammaz te sanna.   **sdq=sqds**    \n" --> **Match!** you can insert description that includes spaces too.
- "qsdqsd=\nsdsdsd\n" --> **Match a multiline pair too**!
- "sdqsd=\n" --> **DO NOT Match**! (lacking descr)
- "= sdq sqdqsd.\n" --> **DO NOT Match**! (lacking word)

Comment: I would use an @ to inhibit backslash expansion, making it easier to read the regular expression this way

Regex mySplit = new Regex(@"(\w+)\s*=\s*((\w+).*)");

Comment: You'right Mico, 
i screwed up again, but i wrote those lines in a hurry

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expressions

Comment: I'm not down rating your answer but I think this would be a bit over the top.